# Is there a way to create an output form based on Google Sheets data?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

#### What I want to make

Is this possible?
I'd like to create an output form that reads data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet. In the form, users would enter a few values (entering their name and some ID number, for example) and view the corresponding information in the connected spreadsheet but not any other information in the sheet. Something like an output form in Microsoft Access. I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this in Google Sheets using existing tools and maybe some scripting.

More generally, though, any way to create this type of 'limited visibility' on a per-user basis for Google Sheets data would be useful. (The 'protect sheet' function in the menu doesn't accomplish this; see below.)

For reference, my specific use case at the moment is as a teacher and wanting a way for students to see specific information related to them from my student information spreadsheet but while not revealing other students' information. I would have a simple form where they enter a name and maybe some personalized code that I give them so they can see their attendance record or something else. For my purposes, I don't need the form to be extremely secure as none of the information is all that sensitive (although more secure is better), but I don't want to be just putting all the information there in front of them by giving them access to the entire sheet.

#### What I've tried so far

I made a new spreadsheet file with two sheets; one sheet was visible to function as a form, and the second sheet was not visible (which I accomplished via the 'protect' menu option). I used `importrange()` to read in the relevant data from my primary spreadsheet to the new spreadsheet's non-visible sheet. On the visible sheet, students entered their name from a drop-down and entered their student ID as validation. If the student's name and ID matched, the first sheet did a `vlookup()` to read in information from the protected sheet and some information from their student record.

Here's what I made, in case my description doesn't make sense: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cHO2jzMh1mkXvlLh-M4eYqN7v11t95-GnfWqL5IwQ14&authuser=0

This had two problems, one small and one big.

The small problem was that every student could see the "form" sheet at the same time. If two students opened the spreadsheet at the same time they would see any information that the other student had entered. I handled this by writing a simple script to automatically reset the "form's" input cells after 20 seconds. Also, any time the form was opened by a new person, the "form's" output cells were erased. So, obviously not a brilliant solution, but for my purposes, this was mostly good enough.

The big problem was that Google's own preview viewer (built into Google Drive and the like) ignores protected ranges and sheets and displays the entire contents a spreadsheet. (Normally, protected sheets are not visible at all and don't appear in the list of sheets at the bottom of the screen unless the viewer has access to them.)
In my case this meant included the protected one that shouldn't have been visible at all, rendered as if it were a print preview, meaning the students were actually able to view all of the other students' data in one big table.

Comment: What is the potential for the number of simultaneous users? Do all of the students have Google accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Are you familiar with [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)?

An Apps Script Web App allows you among others to output selected Google Document contents into a browser.

Hereby, you can use the method `Session.getActiveUser()` to obtain the email of the user and dynamically adjust the data the user is going to obtain in function of his email (BTW, you can also use `Session.getActiveUser()` in the spreadsheet, to detect the user automatically instead of asking him for his name).

**Simple example workflow:**

1. Replace in column A student names through student emails (the Gmail addresses with which the users authenticate their sessions and access Google Sheets)
2. Bind to the spreadsheet a script with a content similar to the following:

```
function doGet(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
  var range=ss.getDataRange();
  var values=range.getValues();
  var user=Session.getActiveUser(); 
  var output="";
    for(var i=1;i<ss.getLastRow();i++){
      if(values[i][0]==user){
        for(var j=1;j<ss.getLastColumn();j++){
          output+=(values[i][j])+" ";
       }
     }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(output));
}
```

Make sure that you have a `doGet()` function and a `return` statement.

3. After running the script once manually to trigger authorization flow, deploy it as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) - executing it as `User accessing the web app` and giving access to `Anyone` (unless desired otherwise).
4. Copy the URL of your WebApp and forward it to your student.
5. When the student open the URL in their browser - they will obtain their results - provided their email is listed in the sheet.

> Please note that the code provided is a simple sample, that retrieves
>   all data and outputs it as a string. Feel free to modify the script
>   e.g.  retrieving only columns of interest and outputting the data as a
>   html table, rather than a simple string.

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with Web Apps other than knowing that it exists, but with what you've outlined I can likely figure out how to get it working. Knowing that it's possible is a big help. You have my gratitude.

Comment: If I may ask one follow-up question: would `Session.getActiveUser()` create a different version of the webpage for each student who views it? (If two people open the page at the same time, would it work for both of them or would one of them see the other's information?)
I ask because you mentioned that I can use `Session.getActiveUser()` within the spreadsheet as well, but I'm fairly certain that wouldn't load separate versions of the spreadsheet on a per-user basis.

Comment: `Session.getActiveUser()` would return the user logged in into a browser session - the only criteria is that the user is logged in with the same (google) account, as his email in your spreadsheet. In other words, if 10 users open the URL, each one with his device -each one will have a different result output as text / html in their browser and none of them will see the actual spreadsheet or the result of other users.